# Faster way of using interp1d in 2d array

Tags: numpy, scipy

The results are correct. But in my real problem, the data are too large, so I want to directly apply interpolation with out using
for loop. Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d


data = np.array([[99,0,3,4,5],
               [6,7,0,9,10],
               [11,22,0,14,15]],dtype=np.float32)

data[data==0] = np.nan

def gap_fill(y):
    not_nan = ~np.isnan(y)
    x = np.arange(len(y))
    interp = interp1d(x[not_nan], y[not_nan], kind='linear')
    ynew = interp(x)
    return ynew

results = []
for d in data:
   gapfilled = gap_fill(d)
   results.append(gapfilled)
print results

[array([ 99.,  51.,   3.,   4.,   5.]), array([  6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.]), array([ 11.,  22.,  18.,  14.,  15.])]
```

Comment: What's the size of `data` in your real problem?

Comment: You don't want to check for precise zero when you have an array of floats. Also, you might numpy's vectorize on your gap_fill.

Comment: Reshape `data` to 1d, and do the 1d interp with multiple gaps.

Comment: @JohnZwinck it is (50000, 50000).

Comment: @hpaulj the linear model should be constrained for each row.

Comment: @hpaulj Do you know what is the default windows size for linear interpolation in the source code of interp1d? If that was less than 5 or 7 then your idea is GREAT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I was thinking of, on the spur of the moment, was:

```
In [8]: gap_fill(data.flatten()).reshape(data.shape)
Out[8]: 
array([[ 99.,  51.,   3.,   4.,   5.],
       [  6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.],
       [ 11.,  22.,  18.,  14.,  15.]])
```

That works for your example because all the `nan` are internal to the rows.  However for elements on the ends of the rows, this turns extrapolation into interpolation across rows, which you probably don't want.

Strictly speaking linear interpolation is finding the value BETWEEN two points, `(1-a)*x1+a*x2`, where `0<=a<=1`.  If `a` is outside of that range, that's linear extrapolation.

The default action in `interp1` is to raise an error in extrapolation cases.  Since your iterative `gap_fill` runs, you must not have any extrapolation cases.  In which case my flatten solution should work fine.

It doesn't look like `interp1d` uses any C code for liner interpolation.  Also looking at its documentation, you might gain some speed by adding `copy=False, assume_sorted=True`.

Its core action is:

```
    slope = (y_hi - y_lo) / (x_hi - x_lo)[:, None]
    y_new = slope*(x_new - x_lo)[:, None] + y_lo
```